# Create a numpy array of the form [1,x,x^2,...,x^n]

Tags: python, numpy

for a value x I want to create a numpy array of the form [1,x,x^2,x^3,...,x^n]. I found the function `numpy.fromfunction`, but i can't get it working. I tried the following:

```
np.fromfunction(lambda i: np.power(x,i), 10, dtype=int)
```

Can somebody explain why this doesn't work and how I can do this?
I know I can do this with a for loop, but I would prefer to use a numpy function.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your variable `x` then you can just do

```
>>> x = 3
>>> np.power(x, np.arange(10))
array([    1,     3,     9,    27,    81,   243,   729,  2187,  6561, 19683], dtype=int32)
```

If you want `x` to be a matrix, just ensure that the dimensions are compatible, e.g.

```
>>> x = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                  [2, 2, 2],
                  [3, 3, 3],
                  [4, 4, 4]])
>>> np.power(x, np.arange(3))
array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  2,  4],
       [ 1,  3,  9],
       [ 1,  4, 16]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: this is nice. Does this also work, if for example x is a matrix?

Comment: yes it will, as long as the dimensions are compatible.

Comment: which dimensions should be compatible? I thought for a matrix x np.power(x,i) is just every entry raised to the power i?

Comment: See my example above

Answer (score 2):

CoryKramer answer is likely the best way of achieving your desired result, but if you wanted to adapt your current approach to the problem, the code below would work:

```
np.fromfunction(lambda _, i: np.power(x,i), (1, 10), dtype=int)
```

For `x = 3`, this produces:

```
[    1,     3,     9,    27,    81,   243,   729,  2187,  6561, 19683]
```

This is because you were providing the value `10` for the array shape, instead of an iterable. The lambda function must then accept two values, so `_` is used to collect the first value (which is always 0 for an array with the shape `(1, 10)`).